# Can’t connect securely to this page

Tags: ssl-certificate, java, windows-10, internet-explorer, jetty

Facing an issue while checking my application compatibility with IE11 in windows10 but it is throwing the below exception while accessing the URL.

**Can’t connect securely to this page**

**This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.**

Note : Same application is working fine in Windows 7 IE11.

Application has Silverlight as frond-end and Embedded Jetty Server as backend.

Java Version : 1.8(jdk180_66-b64), Jetty Version : 9.2.15.v20160210, Silverlight version : 5.1.50906.0

Any pointers is really helpful.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful : update the question with silverlight version.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: Before reaching out this forum i tried all those but none of them resolved my issue.

Comment: Most probably Jetty (which I guess is responsible for SSL) is using outdated and insecure SSL Ciphers that have been removed from IE11 in Win10, but not from Win7. Updating Jetty should resolve this. Edit: Accordig to [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/CipherSuites) Java is responsible for the ciphers jetty can use. You might have to update Java as well and configure jetty to use the correct ciphers.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider : I am using java 8 (jdk180_66-b64) and Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210). Can you suggest which version of jetty & java will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a very detailed report on your SSL configuration and issues from the site https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/.  This may help you discover what the issue is.

Comment: Only if the application is accessible to the Internet. It won't do much for an intranet app.

Comment: @BillThor : Thanks for replying. Unfortunately i can't use it as it is intranet site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You can get a similar report using `nmap`.  See https://www.systemajik.com/blog/securing-tls/ for how I tested my SSL.